# Something wrong with my y-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently my code is:

```
ggplot(data.frame,
       aes(y = Less.Than.1.Year, x = Rate)) +
  geom_point()
```

I am getting the following graph, but the y values in the axis are jumbled up like this:

[image: Graph 1]

What could be the reason?

Also, when I add more data points to the same data frame and in the same format, it gets completely messed up, like this:

[image: Graph 2]

Data format:
[Rate Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ACAz.png)
[Less.Than.1.Year Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFUcC.png)

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I'd guess you have a factor instead of numeric variable on your y-axis

Comment: Thank you! How can I figure out if this is the case, and if so, how can I change it?

Comment: `class(a)` tells you the class of some object `a`, such as a data frame column. If it's a factor, convert to numeric

Comment: Thank you very much! This partially fixed the problem, but now my x-axis only displays three values, even though I have close to 18 distinct x-values that are repeated multiple times for each y-value. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Like I said, we can't see any of your data and we can't run your code without it, so I don't know

Comment: Apologies, I understand what you mean now. I added the descriptive statistics of my data at the end of the post. 
The Rate variable is interest rate points between 0.00 and 5.00
The Less.Than.1.Year is percentage points between 0.00 and 100.00

Thank you again!

Comment: The link in my first comment has several suggested ways to post data. We can't run code on a picture of a printout of descriptive statistics, and that doesn't show the types of your data. Either way, I'm almost certain the issue is that you're plotting a factor where you want to plot a numeric